# examples of continuous function, open set

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

(a) Give an example of a continuous function and an open set U such that $f(U)$ is not open.

(b) Give an example of a continuous function and a set U, which is not open, such that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.

(c) Give an example of a continuous function and a sequence $p_n$ such that $f(p_n)$ converges but $p_n$ does not converge.

(d) Suppose $f$ is continuous function, then give an example to show that if K is compact, then $f^{-1}(K)$ is not necessarily compact.

**For (a)**

Let $f(x) = sin$ $x$, and U be $(-2\pi, 2\pi)$, then $f(U)$ is $[-1,1]$, which is not open.

**For (b)**

Let $f(x) = arctan$ $x$, and U be $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is $(-\infty, \infty)$, which is open.

**For (c)**

Let $f(x) = x^2$, and $p_n = (-1)^n$. $p_n$ does not converge as $n \rightarrow \infty$ but $f(p_n) = (-1)^{2n} = 1^n$ convenes to 1 as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

**For (d)**

Same as in (b)

I am not so sure about (a) and (b), well also (d).

Comment: All your answers are correct. Why are you not sure? Which of the conditions in the requirement do you feel unsure you are meeting? You did a good job!

Comment: I am not so sure about choosing U. I just think it is slightly wrong.

Comment: In (a), U is open, and its image is indeed $[-1, 1]$ which is not open. You meet all the requirements. Similarly in (b) your U is not open, and the preimage is all of $\mathbb R$, which is open.

Answer (score 2):

For all four, how about $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$?